# How abelian group is defined on factor groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra

For def. of solvable groups in the book:

> If a group has a sequence of subgroups, say $G=H_n⊃H_{n−1}⊃···⊃H_1⊃H_0={\{e}\}$, where each subgroup $H_i$ is normal in $H_{i+1}$ and each of the factor groups $H_{i+1} /H_i$ is abelian, then $G$ is a solvable group.

My question is: I know what abelian group is but I don't know how is the definition of $H_{i+1} /H_i$ to be abelian?  Is it : '$\forall h\in H_{i+1} : hH_i=H_ih$' but this already has been considered in 'where each subgroup $H_i$ is normal in $H_{i+1}$' or is it $H_{i+1}H_i=H_iH_{i+1}$?.

How abelian group is defined on factor groups?

PS the book has used $⊃$ notation for subgroup rather than $>$.

Comment: The definition for abelian is the same for all groups. Applied to a quotient group $G/H$ (with $H$ normal subgroup of $G$) it means that $abH=baH$ for all $(a,b) \in G$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net: and, what it would be the definition, if H **is not** normal subgroup of G? (I mean definition for the general case) Thank you

Comment: If $H$ is not normal subgroup of $G$, then $G/H$ will not be a factor group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general Let $G$ be a group and $H$ be it's normal subgroup. Then the factor group $G/H$ is abelian $\Rightarrow g_1g_2H=g_2g_1H, \forall g_1,g_2\in G$.

Coming back to your situation, the factor group $H_{i+1}/H_{i}$ is abelian $\Rightarrow h_1h_2H_i=h_2h_1H_i, \forall h_1,h_2 \in H_{i+1}$.

Answer (score 1):

$H_{i+1}/H_i$ is abelian if and only it it contains the *derived subgroup* of $H_{i+1}$, i.e. the subgroup of $H_{i+1}$ generated by its *commutators*: $\{\,hkh^{-1}k^{-1}\mid h,k\in H_{i+1}\,\}$ (this last set is not stable by products).